# Pinescript - function should be called on each calculation

Tags: pine-script

I'm getting this error
line 5: The function 'sma' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope.

I'm trying to figure out why and can't fix it.  It's a built in indicator on tradingview which I want to adapt but I'm stuck before I can even begin.  Script works but I'd like it without advisories

```
//@version=4
study(title="Williams Alligator", shorttitle="Alligator", overlay=true, resolution="")
smma(src, length) =>
    smma =  0.0
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma(src, length) : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length
    smma
jawLength = input(13, minval=1, title="Jaw Length")
teethLength = input(8, minval=1, title="Teeth Length")
lipsLength = input(5, minval=1, title="Lips Length")
jawOffset = input(8, title="Jaw Offset")
teethOffset = input(5, title="Teeth Offset")
lipsOffset = input(3, title="Lips Offset")
jaw = smma(hl2, jawLength)
teeth = smma(hl2, teethLength)
lips = smma(hl2, lipsLength)
plot(jaw, "Jaw", offset = jawOffset, color=#3BB3E4)
plot(teeth, "Teeth", offset = teethOffset, color=#FF006E)
plot(lips, "Lips", offset = lipsOffset, color=#36C711)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out
I've inserted a line and declared smma value 'sma(src, length)' instead of '0' before the conditional line
Get exact same results without error

```
smma(src, length) =>
    smma = sma(src, length) 
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? smma : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length
    smma
```